# CPU usage on SPARK HISTORY SERVER are 100%

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera

CPU usage on SPARK HISTORY SERVER are 100%, it is a correct behavior on spark history server?

I use CDH 5.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I deleted all old logs, cpu usage has been decreased!

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool -find /user/spark/applicationHistory -mtime +7 | xargs hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash
```

I think that my cloudera version has this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect the spark history server to be at 100% CPU. I would check the heap size of the spark history server and if it is maxed out, consider adding more.